# Postgresql-Calculate difference between rows based on date and time

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I've the following values in my Table1 :

| Date | Time | Id | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:10 | Key_001_C | 1557 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_002_01_C | 10323 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_002_02_C | 8405 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_010_C | 122 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:08 | Key_101_01_C | 6591 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_101_02_C | 6614 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_102_1_C | 6441 | kWh |
| 2024-01-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_102_2_C | 6329 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:02 | Key_001_C | 2557 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:05 | Key_002_01_C | 9323 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:10 | Key_002_02_C | 9405 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_010_C | 222 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_101_01_C | 7591 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_101_02_C | 7614 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_102_1_C | 5441 | kWh |
| 2024-02-01 | 06:00:01 | Key_102_2_C | 7329 | kWh |

What would be the best way, querying at any time/any day on February (and so on, thus January to December...), to get month differences between Id's one-by-one, ignoring the seconds in the time ?

Day starts/ends at 06:00am for me (so January starts on Jan, 1st at 6:00am and ends on Feb, 1st at 6:00am).

Of course, I've values every hour (to be ignored).

I'm confused about using the `lag()` function in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "*get month differences*"? Do you want to sum up all values by month, then get their differences?

Comment: Please give an example of the expected result

Comment: Key_001_C|1000 (which is the difference between the value of jan,1st 6:00am and feb,1st 6:00am for this key, and repeated for each unique key.

Comment: Why do you have the date and time in two different columns? That makes it "impossible" to do calculations, you first have to create a single timestamp. Store it as a timestamp and you don't have that issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. And after that, what will be the correct sql syntax to do what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `LAG` function we can describe it as

> We use a Lag() function to access previous rows data as per defined offset value. It is a window function available from SQL Server 2012 onwards. It works similar to a Lead function. In the lead function, we access subsequent rows, but in lag function, we access previous rows. It is a useful function in comparing the current row value from the previous row value.

If you use the following SQL, I believe you will be able to accomplish your goal.

```
WITH RankedData AS (
  SELECT
    Date,
    Time,
    Id,
    Value,
    Unit,
    LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time) AS PrevDate,
    LAG(Time) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time) AS PrevTime,
    LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Date, Time) AS PrevId
  FROM
    YourTable
)
SELECT
  Date,
  Time,
  Id,
  Value,
  Unit,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM 
    CASE WHEN TIME(Time) >= '06:00:00' THEN TIMESTAMP CONCAT(Date, ' ', Time)
         ELSE TIMESTAMP CONCAT(PrevDate, ' ', PrevTime)
    END
  ) AS MonthDiff
FROM
  RankedData;
```

Comment: Got an error 'syntax error at or near "Time"' on this line :
CASE WHEN TIME(Time) >= '06:00:00' THEN CONCAT(Date...
Since I'm using pgadmin, I've tried to enquote the field 'Time' with no more success (single and double quote).

Comment: Maybe you've not noticed I use postgresql. Some function you gave seems not present : TIME, TIMESTAMPDIFF...

Comment: You are correct, I have corrected to postgres like code, have a look.

Comment: Some function are not known, so I've changed the line to :    CASE WHEN "Time" >= '06:00:00' THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT("Date", ' ', "Time"),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
         ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT("PrevDate", ' ', "PrevTime"),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
but despite these changes (hoping they don't break something), I've not one line per key but all the key-date/time values. I just want to have the difference between  the first day at 6:00am of the current month and the last month for each unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with the following lines (without merging date/time fields) :

```
with cte as (
    select
    "Date" as "Date_Ref",
    date_trunc('minute',"Time") as "Time_Ref",
    "Id",
    "Value",
    "Unit"
    from "Table1"
    where date_trunc('minute',"Time") = '06:00:00' and
    (date_trunc('month', "Date") = date_trunc('month', current_date) or date_trunc('month', "Date") = date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' month))
    order by 3 asc , 1 asc
    ),
cte2 as (
    select
    "Date_Ref",
    "Time_Ref",
    "Id",
    "Value",
    "Unit",
    lag("Value",1) over (order by 3 asc , 1 asc) as "Previous"
    from cte
    )
    select
    "Id",
    ("Value" - "Previous") as "Last month",
    "Unit"
    from
    cte2
    where "Date_Ref" = date_trunc('month', current_date)::timestamp::date  
    order by 1 asc
```